# Pyglet Image Viewer Project - How to cache Images in the background without slowing down the program?

Tags: python, image, caching, viewer, pyglet

What I would like to do is make an image viewer program for myself. I started experimenting with pygame and Tkinter but concluded that my best option would be to use pyglet.
What I'm trying to achieve is a fast JPEG viewer with just basic features. The most important feature would be to display images fast. I concluded some kind of image cache is needed to achieve this. Loading images into pyglet as Sprites works great for speed but I need to do this dynamically. A few images should be kept in memory ready for quick display.
While "old" images should be cleared out to prevent RAM and GPU memory from filling up. All this without interfering with the execution of the program and displaying of images that are already in RAM and/or GPU.

---

I chose pyglet because it has a better event loop system than PyGame. Doesn't consume so much CPU. I'm using python 2.7 and latest Pyglet from repository because it supports 64bit Python. What i have so far:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

import sys
import glob
import os

def generateFileList(folder):
    searchstring = folder + "\*.jpg"
    flist = list()
    for match in glob.iglob(searchstring):
        if os.path.isfile(match):
            flist.append(match)
    return flist

class HelloWorldWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HelloWorldWindow, self).__init__(fullscreen=True)

        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            files = list(sys.argv[1:]) #exclude this scripts name
        else:
            print('Not enough arguments... terminating program.')
            raise SystemExit(0)

        folder = os.path.split(files[0])[0]
        self.flist = generateFileList(folder)
        self.loader = pyglet.resource.Loader(folder)
        self.index = 0
        self.ipreloadA = 1
        self.ipreloadB = 0
        self.sprite = False
        self.createSprite(0)

    def next(self):
        if (len(self.flist) - 1) > self.index:
            self.index += 1
        self.setpreload()
        self.createSprite(1)
    def previews(self):
        if self.index > 0:
            self.index -= 1
        self.setpreload()
        self.createSprite(-1)
    def setpreload(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            self.ipreloadA = 0
            self.ipreloadB = 1
        elif self.index == (len(self.flist) - 1):
            self.ipreloadA = self.index - 1
            self.ipreloadB = self.index
        else:
            self.ipreloadA = self.index - 1
            self.ipreloadB = self.index + 1

    def createSprite(self, direction):
        if direction == 0:
            self.image = pyglet.image.load(self.flist[self.index])
        elif direction == -1:
            self.image = self.imageA
        elif direction == 1:
            self.image = self.imageB
        if self.sprite:
            self.sprite.delete()
        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.image)
        self.preload()
    def preload(self):
        if not self.ipreloadA == self.index:
            fName = os.path.basename(self.flist[self.ipreloadA])
            self.imageA = self.loader.image(fName)
        else:
            self.imageA = self.image
        if not self.ipreloadB == self.index:
            fName = os.path.basename(self.flist[self.ipreloadB])
            self.imageB = self.loader.image(fName)
        else:
            self.imageB = self.image

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        if self.sprite:
            self.sprite.draw()

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE:
            pyglet.app.exit()
        elif symbol == key.LEFT:
            self.previews()
        elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
            self.next()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = HelloWorldWindow()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

What I've tried to achieve with above code was that the images get loaded first and then a sprite to be created just before displaying. Problem with the above code is that it still slows down. Seems to wait for images to load from HDD.

Here is a more basic version without my failed atempt:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

import sys
import glob
import os

def generateFileList(folder):
    searchstring = folder + "\*.jpg"
    flist = list()
    for match in glob.iglob(searchstring):
        if os.path.isfile(match):
            flist.append(match)
    return flist

def createSprite(imagePath):
    pass

class HelloWorldWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HelloWorldWindow, self).__init__(fullscreen=True)

        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            files = list(sys.argv[1:]) #exclude this scripts name
        else:
            print('Not enough arguments... terminating program.')
            raise SystemExit(0)

        folder = os.path.split(files[0])[0]
        self.flist = generateFileList(folder)
        self.index = 0
        self.sprite = False
        self.createSprite()

    def next(self):
        if (len(self.flist) - 1) > self.index:
            self.index += 1
        self.createSprite()
    def previews(self):
        if self.index > 0:
            self.index -= 1
        self.createSprite()
    def createSprite(self):
        self.image = pyglet.image.load(self.flist[self.index])
        if self.sprite:
            self.sprite.delete()
        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(self.image)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        if self.sprite:
            self.sprite.draw()

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE:
            pyglet.app.exit()
        elif symbol == key.LEFT:
            self.previews()
        elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
            self.next()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = HelloWorldWindow()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Also note that there is no image resizing here for simplicity.

Comment: It seems i'l need to look into multiprocessing and queues...
Any additional tips are welcome :)